# Python QT5 can't show message box from another class

Tags: python, pyqt5

When I try to show a message box from another class, it doesn't react anything.

On the other hand, I could succeed to show the box with the internal function.

I can print a message in console through another method of the class.

It seems just not working without any error.. I'm reading some articles but doesn't help.. Could you let me know which part I missed?

[Main.py]

```
class WinViewer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Autolin')
        self.move(300, 300)
        self.resize(400, 200)

        crw = Crawler.Crawler()
        runBtn = QPushButton('Run', self)
        runBtn.move(150, 50)
        runBtn.clicked.connect(crw.putWebData)

        tstBtn = QPushButton('Tst', self)
        tstBtn.move(150, 100)
        tstBtn.clicked.connect(self.tstmsg)

        crw.testFunc()

        self.show()

    def tstmsg(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Tst", "Tst works.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = WinViewer()

    gui.initUI()

    sys.exit(q_app.exec_())
```

[Sub.py]

```
class Crawler():
    def putWebData(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Run", "Run works.")

    def testFunc(self):
        print('Hello')
```

Comment: Change `crw = Crawler.Crawler()` to `crw = Crawler()`

Comment: Then, It showed an error like "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"..

Comment: and that ^ since your file is named Sub.py you can import the Crawler class like this. ```from Sub import Crawler```

Comment: When I specify the file name with 'from' stmt, then the error doesn't show. However, I still have no answer from the Window.

Comment: try using the answer below

Comment: I tried to debug, but it seems not getting in the Crawler class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this

> **Main.py**

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
from Sub import Crawler


class WinViewer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(WinViewer, self).__init__(*args)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Autolin')
        self.move(300, 300)
        self.resize(400, 200)

        crw = Crawler(self)
        runBtn = QPushButton('Run', self)
        runBtn.move(150, 50)
        runBtn.clicked.connect(crw.putWebData)

        tstBtn = QPushButton('Tst', self)
        tstBtn.move(150, 100)
        tstBtn.clicked.connect(self.tstmsg)

        crw.testFunc()

        self.show()

    def tstmsg(self):
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Tst", "Tst works.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q_app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    gui = WinViewer()
    gui.initUI()

    sys.exit(q_app.exec_())
```

> **Sub.py**

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Crawler(QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Crawler, self).__init__(*args)

    def putWebData(self):
        self.about(self, "Run", "Run works.")

    def testFunc(self):
        print('Hello')
```

**[EDIT]**
I went to do something which gave me no time to add the explanation.

What you missed is the `super().__init__()` is a must when you are inheriting a class from Qt Classes and it works like this `super({CLASS_NAME}, self)` self represents the inherited class and after it `.__init__(*args, **kwargs)` it should have both args and kwargs so you can get the full functionality of the inhereted class. `*args, **kwargs` should be assigned as attributes inside `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: When I tried this way, It shows the error like "line 15, in initUI
    crw = Crawler()
TypeError: __init__() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given".

Comment: I put __init__(self), then it doesn't show the error, but I get no message box yet.

Comment: add ```self``` inside the Crawler class

Comment: Im guessing that the QWidget won't show the message box

Comment: Hmmm.. however, the message box is shown by the internal function..

Comment: I updated my code with yours newly, but it shows like "TypeError: QWidget(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 2 has unexpected type 'NoneType'"

Comment: delete the ```parent=None``` and its reference from the super() method below it

Comment: When I removed from "parent=None" from __init__ and its references, then it doesn't show the mesage box..

Comment: You need to call ```super().__init__(self)``` but not the reference of parent.

Comment: Now, main is using "    def __init__(self):  super().__init__()"
And, sub is using "    def __init__(self):  super().__init__()"

Comment: add self in Sub as well

Comment: When I put class "WinViewer(QWidget): def __init__(self): super().__init__(self)", then it shows like "RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type WinViewer was never called"

Comment: It's now showing an error, but says "Cannot find reference 'connect' in 'function' in both tstBtn and runBtn. However, tstBtn shows the message box.

Comment: I have tested the code above myself it should work.

Comment: Downvoted as there is no explanation what to change, just sample code. This does'nt really help anyone learn how to get it right

Comment: Well Im just like you a beginner in Qt but I created a Semi-Operating system, what you missed is the ```super().__init__()``` is a must when you are inheriting a class from Qt Classes and it works like this ```super({CLASS_NAME}, self)``` self represents the inherited class and after it ```.__init__(*args, **kwargs)``` it should have both args and kwargs so you can get the full functionality of the inhereted class. ```*args, **kwargs``` should be assigned as attributes inside ```def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the reason why I have to use two parameters instead of default, (). Here, I record the URL for this. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super
. Hope to get someone understood. And, I really appreciate to you Aoof XD.. Thank you. :)